# Monitoring resumable file upload in Google Drive v3

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am writing my own wrapper around Google Drive API v3 in Python. I have a small problem with uploading files and seeing what is going on. Here is a small sample code

```
# create service using oauth2flow -> drive_service
# upload pdf from disk
media = MediaFileUpload('/files/test.pdf', resumable=True)

file_metadata = {'name': 'test.pdf'}

res = drive_service.files().create(
    body=file_metadata,
    media_body=media,
    fields="id"
)
```

Everything works fine, but I am not able to see how many bytes have been transferred so far (like in download I have `next_chunk` method). Also, I do not really know how to use the functionality of `resumable=True` in case of error. One more thing, if I put `chunksize` variable into `MediaFileUpload` I get 400 Bad Request Error. Is it possible to have similar functionality like in download method where I can upload files in pieces and monitor what is going on?

EDIT:

@Tanaike solved the problem. You can keep track of upload by using `next_chunk` method but the `chunkize` needs to be multiple of 256 KB.
Here is a sample code:

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 256 * 1024
DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024

media = MediaFileUpload('/files/test.pdf', resumable=True, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE)

file_metadata = {'name': 'test.pdf'}

res = drive_service.files().create(
    body=file_metadata,
    media_body=media,
    fields="id"
)

response = None
while response is None:
    status, response = res.next_chunk()

    try:
        sys.stdout.write('%d/%d Bytes transfered' % (status.resumable_progress, status.total_size))     
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I am looking at the source code: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py and 'next_chunk' method works only with resumable option. `Content-Range` and `Content-Length` header are set inside `next_chunk` method. I still do not knwo why am I getting error when using `chunksize`.

Comment: For Q1 and Q2, You can see the progress information and the exception handling pattern. Please check [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload#resumable-media-chunked-upload).

Comment: For Q3 and Q4, for example, how about this? ``Chunk size restriction: There are some chunk size restrictions based on the size of the file you are uploading. Files larger than 256 KB (256 * 1024 B) must have chunk sizes that are multiples of 256 KB. For files smaller than 256 KB, there are no restrictions. In either case, the final chunk has no limitations; you can simply transfer the remaining bytes.``. If these are not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike it actually worked! The chunksize needs to be multiple of 256 KB. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.